# Android buttons are only clickable on the corners

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a simple LinearLayout with several buttons, whos state color/text change based on the state of an underlying service, thats working fine.

However the buttons, are only clickable on the right corner ???

The button allSystemServicesToggleButton which i have included the implementation for in this post and only be clicked on the right side/right corner???

**Here is my fragment xml layout & Actual screen shot with  “Show Layout bounds” set to true:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="All System Services"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/allSystemServicesToggleButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/stopped"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/stoppedServiceColor"
        android:enabled="true"/>



</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/shutdown_all_services"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shutdownAllServicesToggleButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/shutdown"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:enabled="true"/>



</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:text="Networks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewServicesDivider1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#808080"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="Bluetooth Service"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btServicesToggleButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/stopped"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/stoppedServiceColor"/>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<!--TODO: get requirements for showing paired devices & pairing devices-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textPairedText"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="5"
      android:text="Paired Bluetooth Devices"
      android:textColor="#000000"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
      />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textViewNumberOfConnectedDevices"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="0"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/btDevicesToggleButton"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="2"
      android:text="Pair"

      />

</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="MQTT Service"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MQTTserviceToggleButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/stoppedServiceColor"
        android:text="@string/stopped" />

</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:text="Location Services"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewServicesDivider3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#808080"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="GPS"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gpsServiceToggleButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/stopped"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/stoppedServiceColor"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:text="Command Services"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewServicesDivider4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#808080"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="Voice Recognition"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/voiceRecognitionToggleButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/stopped"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/stoppedServiceColor"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**Relevant fragment java:**

```
package x.core.fragments;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import x.core.Application.NgfrApp;
import x.core.R;
import x.core.helpers.Util;
import x.core.services.BluetoothService;
import x.core.services.LocationService;
import x.core.services.MqttBrokerService;
import x.core.services.ServicesStateBroadcastReceiver;
import x.core.services.SpeechRecognitionService;
import x.core.services.UIService;


public class ServicesFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "ServicesFragment";

    public static ServicesFragment newInstance() {
        return new ServicesFragment();
    }

    private static Button btServicesToggleButton;
    private static Button mqttServicesToggleButton;
    private static Button gpsServiceToggleButton;
    private static Button voiceServiceToggleButton;
    private static Button allServiceToggleButton;


    private static String stopped = null;
    private static String running = null;
    private static int runningColorId, stoppedColorId = -1;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_services, container, false);
        btServicesToggleButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btServicesToggleButton);
        mqttServicesToggleButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.MQTTserviceToggleButton);
        gpsServiceToggleButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.gpsServiceToggleButton);
        voiceServiceToggleButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.voiceRecognitionToggleButton);
        allServiceToggleButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.allSystemServicesToggleButton);
        stopped = getResources().getString(R.string.stopped);
        running = getResources().getString(R.string.running);
        runningColorId = getResources().getColor(R.color.runningServiceColor);
        stoppedColorId = getResources().getColor(R.color.stoppedServiceColor);
        allServiceToggleButton.setEnabled(true);
        allServiceToggleButton.setClickable(true);
        allServiceToggleButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;


    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.allSystemServicesToggleButton:
                if (ServicesStateBroadcastReceiver.BT_SERVICE_STATE_VALUE==false ||  ServicesStateBroadcastReceiver.MQTT_STATE_VALUE==false || ServicesStateBroadcastReceiver.NGFR_GPS_SERVICE_STATE_VALUE==false || ServicesStateBroadcastReceiver.VOICE_SERVICE_STATE_VALUE==false)
                {

         Toast.makeText(NgfrApp.getContext(),NgfrApp.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.restarting_services),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                 //restartingServices(); 
        }
        else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(NgfrApp.getContext(),NgfrApp.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.all_already_running),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
                default: 
                    break; 
        }
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_tabLyout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />



</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java, I only included relevant code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends  AppCompatActivity {
    private static String TAG = "Main";

    private static final int CHECK_BT_CODE = 1;
    private static final int CHECK_TTS_CODE = 2;
    //global boolean flags that will communicate the state of the system at all times
    //bluetooth related flags
    public boolean isBleSupported = false;
    public boolean isBluetoothEnabled = false;
    public boolean accessBluetoothManager= false;
    public boolean nearbyDevices = false;
    //configuration data related
    public boolean isConfigurationLoadedCorrectly = false;
    //text to speech related
    public boolean isTextToSpeechSupported = false;


    private Context context = null;
    private ServicesStateBroadcastReceiver servicesStateBroadcastReciever = null;
    private ViewPager mainViewPager;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "Activity started!!");
        context = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MainActivityViewPager adapter = new MainActivityViewPager(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mainViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_viewPager);
        mainViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout)  findViewById(R.id.activity_main_tabLyout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mainViewPager );
}

}
```

**The adapter for my fragments, FragmentStatePagerAdapter:**

```
package x.core.views;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import x.BiometricsFragment;
import x.ServicesFragment;

public class MainActivityViewPager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public MainActivityViewPager(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment returnFragment;

        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                returnFragment = ServicesFragment.newInstance();
                break;
            case 1:
                returnFragment = BiometricsFragment.newInstance();
                break;
            default:
                return null;
        }

        return returnFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        CharSequence title;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                title = "Services";
                break;
            case 1:
                title = "Biometrics";
                break;
            default:
                return null;
        }

        return title;


    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your layout works fine for me. Try maybe to isolate the problem by either commenting out code until the issue stops appearing, or by creating a new empty fragment and adding stuff to it until reproducible. BTW, `layout_weight` is usually used with width or height of `0dp`. Not sure what is the expected behavior in your case.

Comment: @DennisK hi i commented all the GUI code in xml & java except the top button, still the same issue, its very odd.

Comment: It is odd. Are you running in the emulator or on a device? Maybe try different targets. Also, posting your activity xml/code could be helpful

Comment: @DennisK, Im testing on Galaxy S8 Active & Galaxy S8 both running Android OS 7.0.

Comment: I actually changed the Button to a clickable TextView and Im still having the same issue!

Comment: I wonder if something in your activity is overlapping the fragment's container. Maybe try to create a new app with a single activity and a button and see if that works.

Comment: @DennisK, per your suggestion I created a new project & I copied pasted the services xml directly into an the activity xml without any fragments, the and the issue is resolved. Therefore why is my fragment implementation altering the clickable area of the button & how can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Can you share a screenshot, where "Show layout bounds" is turned on?

Comment: @azizbekian, apologies for the delay, I uploaded a screen shot with  debug.layout true.

Answer (score 2):

only for corner clicking use this kind of logic

```
<FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvtttt"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:background="#F00" />


            </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I actually DO NOT want corner clicking, i just want regular click area.